# Eclipse NDK build error 'Add' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm new to NDK and JNI and not sure how to fix this error.  I manually copy libMathFuncLib.so, mathFuncsLibs.cpp and MathFuncLibs.h files to Eclipse project.  When I run this command 'ndk-build' and I get back 'workspace/test/jni/TestMath.cpp: error: 'Add' was not declared in this scope.'

Here is my folder structure:

```
-test
   |__src
       |__ExecuteTest.java
       |__MainActivity.java

   |__jni
       |__Android.mk
       |__Application.mk
       |__TestMath.cpp

   |__libs
       |__armeabi

   |__myLibs
       |__armeabi
           |__libMathFuncLib.so

   |__myNatives
       |__MathFuncLibs.cpp
       |__MathFuncLib.h
```

Here is MathFuncLib.h file:

```
//This is static library example    

#ifndef MathFuncLib_INCLUDED
#define MathFuncLib_INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif   

    class MyMathFunc
    {

    public:

        static int Add(int a, int b);  
        static int Subtract(int a, int b);
        static int Multiply(int a, int b);
        static double Divide(int a, int b);

    };

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
#endif
```

Here is MathFuncLib.cpp file:

```
#include "MathFuncLib.h"

    int MyMathFunc::Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    int MyMathFunc::Subtract(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    int MyMathFunc::Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFunc::Divide(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
```

Here is MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;//to use TextView
import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;//to use LayoutParams

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

        int retVal = 0;
        ExecuteTest et = new ExecuteTest();
        retVal = et.TestAdd();            

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(150, 50, 200, 0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(retVal));
        setContentView(tv);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is ExecuteTest.java file:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.util.Log;

public class ExecuteTest {

    public int ReturnValue(){
        return 50;
    }

    public native int TestAdd();

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("MathFuncLib");
        System.loadLibrary("Arithmetic");

        Log.i ("ExecuteTest", "Shared Libs loaded");
    }       
}
```

Here is TestMath.cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "../myNatives/MathFuncLib.h"

extern "C"
{

    JNIEXPORT int  JNICALL Java_com_example_test_ExecuteTest_TestAdd(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Test", "Inside TestAdd()");

        int retVal= Add(50,50);//Add(,) is a method inside MathFuncLib.so file
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Here us my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MathFuncLib-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../myLibs/armeabi/libMathFuncLib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Arithmetic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TestMath.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form for

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI         := x86              ## -- set to whatever platform you need
APP_PLATFORM    := android-9
APP_STL         := stlport_static   ## -- USE IT
```

.

As for Android.mk you will need 2, because I see you want to build a solution using two projects --

a native (non-JNI) library

2nd native (JNI) library, that loads the first and makes it available to JAVA through JNI

Application.mk should be duplicated.

.

Android.mk (the **native** part)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#
# --------------- C / C++ Project settings ---------------
#
LOCAL_PATH              := _path_to__myNatives

# Application/Library Name
LOCAL_MODULE            := MathFunc

# Project Source files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := MathFuncLibs.cpp

# Compiler Flags
LOCAL_CFLAGS            := -mfpu=neon

### THIS BIT BELOW IS IMPORTANT -- used so that projects that include this build output will find the correct headers ###

# Location of headers
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/.
#
# ------------------------- .. ----------------------------
#

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

.

You would be using Eclipse, so you can then find the output in **_path_to__myNatives/obj/local/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libMathFunc.a**. $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) evaluates to x86 in this example.
Need to build once for your platform (specified in Application.mk).

.

Android.mk  (the **native JNI** part )

*replace "Static" with "Shared" (no quotes ofc)*

```
#
# -------------- Dependant Static Libraries Linkage ---------------
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH              := _path_to__myNatives

LOCAL_MODULE            := MathFuncLib ## can be different from the previous module name definition in Android.mk or can be the same

LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := $(LOCAL_PATH)/obj/local/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libMathFunc.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
#
# ------------------------- .. ----------------------------
#

#
# --------------- C / C++ Project settings ----------------
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH              := _path_to___jni

# Application/Library Name
LOCAL_MODULE            := Arithmetic

# Project Source files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := TestMath.cpp

# Compiler Flags
LOCAL_CFLAGS            := -mfpu=neon

LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -lz

# Static Libraries
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := MathFuncLib # must be exactly the same as in THIS .mk file

# Shared Libraries
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MathFuncLib # must be exactly the same as in THIS .mk file
#
# ------------------------- .. ----------------------------
#

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I don't think I want to build solution for two projects.  I just want Java to call into Math(int,int) that is in C++ library, so I just built that C++ library into shared library and copied it to Eclipse project folder, myNatives.  The reason I copied MathFuncLib.cpp into myNatives folder because I was not sure so I just did it anyway.  To what i understand, I need JNI portion to call into C++ function Math(int,int) from Java.  So that is basically it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. If you don't want 2 libraries, just include the sources inside the second Android.mk file and remove the "--- Dependant Static Libraries Linkage ---" part

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my fixed.

1) in my MyMathFunc.h file, I shouldn't use "extern C" because C does not support class.  If wanting to use "extern C" then I have to remove class declaration.

2) need to change Android.mk and Application.mk files.

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)    
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_MODULE := MathFuncLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../myLibs/armeabi/libMathFuncLib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MathFuncLib    
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../myNatives/    
LOCAL_MODULE := Arithmetic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TestMath.cpp    
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz   

#Tell it to build an APK    
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```